# check string with multiple length patterns

Tags: java, regex

I need to check a string with a regex.

the valid strings are for example: `ABC0001` or `A00023`.

There are three parts I have to check:

1. So the string should start with a word signs: `[a-zA-Z]{1,}`
2. Then there are min one zero: `[0]{1,}`
3. The third part is a number `\\d+`

The whole string may not be longer than 8 signs.

What I tried so far:

```
String NR_PATTERN = "^([a-zA-Z]{1,}[0]{1,}\\d+){3,8}$";
```

The problem is, that the regex do not accepts the string: `KDS0234`

Comment: And the trouble you have with this expression is (other than the fact that you can have arbitrary length strings by inserting zeros or additional letters and that `[0]` is the same as bare-bones `0`)?

Comment: `"^([a-zA-Z]{1,}[0]{1,}\\d+){3,8}$"; ` mean `([a-zA-Z]{1,}[0]{1,}\\d+)` appear 3-8 times, not whole length is 3-8

Comment: Try like this: [`"^(?!.{9})[A-Z]+0+[1-9]\\d*$"`](http://fiddle.re/12v3ha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with a positive lookahead in the beginning:

```
(?=^.{3,8}$)([a-zA-Z]{1,}[0]{1,}\\d+)
```

The positive lookahead:

```
(?=^.{3,8}$)
```

will look ahead `?=` and confirm that from the beginnning `^` to the end `$` of the string, there is any character matched by `.` between 3 and 8 times `{3,8}`.

Answer (score 1):

`(…){3,8}` means you want to … sequence to be repeated between 3 and 8 times, not that the string is 8 characters

You could just use ( in know you said you need a regex, but perhaps this will work for you)

```
String NR_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z]+0+\\d+";
String s = "ABC0001";
boolean match  = s.length() < 8 &&  s.matches(NR_PATTERN);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length condition with a lookahead and then match your pattern:

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,8})([A-Za-z]+0[0-9]+)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
\b(?=[A-Z]+0+\d+)\w{3,8}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jX0uT4/2), in `Java` use double backslashes.

---

This will match:

```
ABC0001 A00023 and ABCD001
```

But not

```
B123456 or 0001B
```

Comment: In the OP: "The whole string may not be longer than 8 signs."

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=^.{3,8}$)([a-zA-Z]+[0]+\d+)
```

Hope this help

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.